# How to fix html video ratio on desktop full screen

Tags: html, css, video, html5-video

I have a website [www.theraplounge.co/](http://www.theraplounge.co/) when I upload a video and put it in full screen on desktop the video ratio mess up. How can I make full screen fit with the video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object-fit (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) property is set to initial in one of the loaded stylesheets.

```css
#video_file video {
    object-fit: contain;    /* Replaces initial */   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that in the CSS the video `height` is set to `450px`, you should set it to `auto` in order to let it grow in height as needed.